# How do you replace previous notifications sent using Cloud Functions? And how do you prevent getting certain notifications?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase to store what I need for the notifications, and Google Cloud Functions to send the notifications. When a user decides to go to an app, they are subscribed to that event so that they can receive the chat notifications.

My first problem is that they are getting separate notifications for each message, and I imagine that would get pretty annoying in a group chat. I tried using collapseKey, but I think I'm either using it wrong or misunderstanding its purpose. Is it not working because the notification has already been sent? Either way, how do I fix this?

My second problem is that users are subscribed to an event, but because there's a bit of a delay in receiving the notification sometimes, they can get their own message notification if they exit the app before the notification is sent. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

For your first problem,
use

> Pending intent flags

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

For more about flags [Please visit this link](https://androidhub.wordpress.com/tag/pending-intent-flags/)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out the PendingIntent solution, but here's what worked for me.

Turns out 'collapseKey' is for when devices are inactive. You can use 'tag' for when the phone is running to replace older notifications.

```
const payload = {
    notification:{
      title: eventName,
      body: message,
      tag: 'chat',
      sound: 'default'
    },
  };
```

For the second part, I just ended up switching to sendToDevice instead of sendToTopic. I didn't know you could send it to more than one device at a time lol. Just a note, the array of registration tokens isn't allowed to be null.